# MS Access 2007 Visual display of events

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, scheduled-tasks, gantt-chart

I am currently working on a database that contains two tables: tblAuthor and tblBooks. I am looking for a way to generate a timline look with a strong visual emphasis. I do not know all the possible oulets for creating reports in Access and any advice (including give up this isn't possible) would be welcome. I am hoping to format it similarly to a Gantt chart.

If there is anyway of doing this, or if you have any other suggestions please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

I work for a company that develops Gantt chart controls. We still develop, maintain and support an ActiveX Edition, which seamlessly integrates into Access. Here is an overview of some key features of the general control:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxc4-R1Kn_4&feature=plcp

If these features do what you want your Gantt to do, then you can download a free trial version from our website. You then should also download the samples collection as this also will provide you with an example of how to directly embed the control into Access. However, make sure that you download the ActiveX version (you have to register first before downloading): http://www.netronic.com/gantt/gantt-software/free-gantt-chart.html

Hope this helps. If you have questions, please send an email to support@netronic.de, and mention the stackoverflow post from Martin. Good luck with your project :-)